# IIS Express HttpContext Identity blank from async call

Tags: c#, iis

I have an issue debugging my project locally using IIS Express, it consists of two projects: a web service and a web site.

The website serves an .html page with a data grid that makes calls to the web service for data. One of the actions is to update the data row using a POST request, the web service httpcontext identity is blank however.

If I place an .aspx page on the website - the httpcontext identity is visible. If I deploy the code to a server, the httpcontext identity is visible. Is there anyway to make it visible through IIS Express? Am I wrong to assume that the httpcontext should be visible through an async call?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this question solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149422/how-do-i-set-the-user-identity-for-tasks-when-calling-task-waitall

Answer (score 0):

I have written a utility function called `CompleteOnBackgroundThread` to solve this problem:

It's messy, but it works.

It can be called like this:

```
ThreadingUtils.CompleteOnBackgroundThread(() => { this.MgrPlayerGroups.DeletePlayerGroup(id).Wait(); });
```

Here's the implementation:

```
public static void CompleteOnBackgroundThread(this Action action)
{
    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Exception exception = null;

    WindowsIdentity appId = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    Action surroundingAction = () =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (WindowsImpersonationContext wi = appId.Impersonate())
            {
                action();
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerExceptions.Count == 1)
            {
                // Get the wrapped exception
                exception = ex.InnerExceptions.First();
            }
            else
            {
                exception = ex;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            mre.Set();
        }
    };
    surroundingAction.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    mre.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    if (exception != null)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```