# C# Async Tasks Losing Impersonation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, task, impersonation

My function consists of three steps. The first step has to be awaited because I need the result of the database call to perform the next two steps. Steps 2 and 3 can be run in the background while the rest of my function executes as I do not need the result from the database for these two calls.

My first call runs smoothly and saves. When I hit the second however, I am losing the Impersonation and am unable to access the database. I'm trying to wrap everything in a using clause with WindowsImpersonationContext, but still I am losing my impersonation.

Here is my code:

```
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate();

using(ctx)
{
    await _service.AddParent(parent);

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _service.AddChildren(parent);
    });
}

// other code doing other things here... I want this to run while the Children are being saved
```

The AddChildren function is losing the Impersonation that the first thread uses, and thus can't access the database.

Am I thinking about this the right way? If so, how can I force all of my Tasks to use the correct impersonation if this using clause isn't the answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149422/how-do-i-set-the-user-identity-for-tasks-when-calling-task-waitall has two answers that look like your situation. One involves changing your using statement, the other involves using alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy if you run this in ASP.net.

Comment: Await the second task or just run `AddChildren` synchronously.